# org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce

Tags: java, maven, optaplanner

I tried to run Optaplanner's vrp-dataset-generator. But I have some errors. And I tried to run Optaplanner web examples but it has also error.

This is Web example Error.

```
##         at 
 org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke 
 (JUnit4Provider.java:128)


Results :

Tests in error:
  JUnit4Provider.invoke:128->executeTestSet:153->executeWithRerun:173-        
>execute:283 ▒ ExceptionInInitializer

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 ---
[INFO] Total time: 01:48 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-28T11:17:13+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 78M/149M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-        
plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project optaplanner-webexamples: There     
are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to F:\optaplanner\optaplanner-master\optaplanner-    
webexamples\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please 
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

And this is vrp-dataset-generator's error.

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (no-managed-deps) @ 
vrpdatasetgenerator ---
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.commonjava.maven.enforcer.rule.EnforceManagedDepsRule 
failed with message:
The following 1 dependencies are NOT using a managed version:

- com.graphhopper:graphhopper:jar
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Total time: 26.236 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-28T11:26:19+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/118M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-    
plugin:1.4.1:enforce (no-managed-deps) on project vrpdatasetgenerator: Some 
Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why 
the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please 
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException ##
```

I think I have some issue in Maven, but I can't find errors.

Please help me.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you building that from source instead of using the release artifacts?

Comment: Well. Main problem is vrp-dataset-generator's error. How can I run this on Maven 3.5.2?

Comment: Based on the above output the current master has some errors in there (unit tests are failing) which should be fixed by the developers...But you have not answered my question? Have you already filed in an issue ?

Comment: Well. I test all step in Optaplanner doc. And in first step, using release artifacts, I use wildfly11.0 so it couldn't start. Because of that error, I built from source instead of using the release artifacts.

Comment: Well. I test all step in Optaplanner doc. And in first step, using release artifacts, I use wildfly11.0. optaplanner web example should set on wildfly 10.0. so it couldn't start.Because of that error, I built from source instead of using the release artifacts. I have run successfully optaplanner web examples but I want to have my own .vrp files.  So I built vrp-dataset-generator but it has error. I can't find why that's happening.

Comment: There are 2 separate, isolated questions in this 1 SO question, please split it up.

Answer (score 0):

This question is mixing 2 separate questions into one question, which creates a lot of confusion. One is about optaplanner-webexamples, one is about the external repo vrp-dataset-generator.

**vrp-dataset-generator** is not a part of OptaPlanner. It's not in the OptaPlanner GitHub repository. It's an experimental repo in my GitHub repo. Some day it might be cleaned up and some of the code might be added in optaplanner-examples (or optashift-vehicle-routing when we start that), but today it's not ready for mass-consumption.

(Anyway, the reason vrp-dataset-generator is apparently failing is in the maven pom, that dependency's version should be declared in dependencyManagment instead of just dependencies.)

**optaplanner-webexamples** should build from source. If it doesn't, well want to figure out why and see if we can improve something in the sources. There's a jenkins job doing also building it and it's green, so it must be something that's different on your local machine. Can you edit your question to include the failing unit test and it's stacktrace? Also state your JDK, maven and wildfly versions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have hoped  your reply.I have mentioned it on optaplanner discussion room. please give me some help.

Comment: And I use jdk 9.0.4 and maven 3.5.2

Comment: well, optaplanner-webexamples works well if i use "mvn clean install -DskipTests". But if i use "mvn clean install" it get this error.